# Linux changes another file content while changing in one file

Tags: linux

i have 3 files a1.ksh,a2.ksh,a3.ksh in same location.whenever i do modification in any one file it is reflecting in remaining 2 files why it is happening.
i am using OS linux
if anyone know why so please let me know

Comment: the other files can be a symbolic link to the file you are modifying; Run 'ls -l' command to confirm on this.

Comment: thanks for reply Viswesn.I did a little modification in my question.if i did modification in any of three file it is reflecting to remaining 2.it means all the file have same symbolic link isn't it?

Comment: Could you post the output of the command `ls -l` in the directory containing the 3 files?